# How Pusher Connection is calculated?

Tags: pusher, pubnub

I am trying to understand the pricing shceme of [Pusher](http://pusher.com/pricing). According to their pricing, the Boostrap allows `100 max. Connections`. My question is this: if I have 10,000 daily visitors to my page, each one subscribed to a different channel to receive messages, how much I need to pay.

With realtime.co it's easier to understand because I know that I pay $1.00 per 1,000,000 messages without any other limitations. So I need to know how to calculate and estimate the total cost for my application, becaues I might designed it in a different way to reduce the costs.

I am considering choosing betwee, PubNub, Pusher and realtime.co, but knowing how to calculate estimated total cost is crucial for me because beginning to develop my application and going with a specific client/server library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the Pusher FAQ post: [How are Connections Counted?](https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412239949969-How-Are-Concurrent-Connections-Counted-)

Comment: Link outdated. Current link:
https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/360019428173-How-are-connections-counted-

Comment: Link again outdated: https://support.pusher.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412239949969-How-Are-Concurrent-Connections-Counted-