# Whats the connection meaning of pusher?

Tags: pusher

I have added pusher to my start up web page, but there is something that is troubling me:

Since I have the sandbox plan (which says that i only have 20 maximum connections) I have been testing my web page on several computers (using pusher), but when I get in to my account it says that I am using 6 connections, even when anyone is not using my web page, so whats does this connections means? how does it counts as a connection? when a web page is closed, the connection counter decrease?

Any information about this will be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Pusher Connection is calculated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254062/how-pusher-connection-is-calculated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The connection count on pricing plans indicates the number of simultaneous connections allowed.
>
> A connection is counted as a WebSocket connection to Pusher. **When using the Pusher JavaScript library a new WebSocket connection is created when you create a new Pusher('APP_KEY'); instance.**
>
> Channel subscriptions are created over the existing WebSocket connection, and do not count towards your connection quota (there is no limit on the number allowed per connection).
>
> Note: **connections automatically close when a user navigates to another web page or closes their web browser so there is no need to do this manually.**