# Maximum connections on pusher

Tags: pusher

I'm trying to understand Pusher.
If I have maximum of 100 connections (Boostrap) does that means that one user can open 100 connections and other also 100. Or first user can open, let's say, 50 and second one also 50 connections, so third cannot open any?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How Pusher Connection is calculated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18254062/how-pusher-connection-is-calculated)

Answer (score 1):

Pusher uses a model of subscribing to channels within a connection. A single user would only need one connection, but could be subscribed to as many channels as you want on that connection.